# How i can use AssumeRole with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

Im trying to execute the Assume_Role for boto3 but i have the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ststest.py", line 7, in <module>
    DurationSeconds=990
  File "/Users/Randal/Desktop/TFG/Venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 269, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Randal/Desktop/TFG/Venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 323, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRole
```

Im using the next code for python:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::533680604961:role/Barney',
    RoleSessionName='auth',
    Policy='{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Action": "s3:*","Resource": "*"}]}',
    DurationSeconds=990

)
```

And my credentials has the API&Secret Key for the users **"Barney"**, and this belong user has the next permissions :

-AdministratorAccess:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

-CreateSTSPolicy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::533680604961:role/AdminAccess"
        }
    ]
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Is the IAM user "Barny" in the account ``533680604961``?  Or in a different account?

Comment: @garnaat in the same account

Comment: Hmm.  The ``RoleArn`` you are specifying in the ``assume_role`` call is ``arn:aws:iam::533680604961:role/Barney`` but the IAM policy is granting permission to assume the role ``arn:aws:iam::533680604961:role/AdminAccess``.  That doesn't look right.